# "Fixing" JSON coming out of MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I'm fetching JSON code stored in MySQL and it has extra slashes, which I have to remove in order to parse it in JavaScript, after I print it on the page. Right now I'm doing the following:

```
$save = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $save); // Replace new line characters with <br>
$save = str_replace('\\"', '"', $save); // top-level JSON
$save = str_replace('\\\\"', '\"', $save); // HTML inside top level JSON
$save = str_replace('\\\\\\\\\\"', '\\\\\"', $save); // HTML inside second level JSON
```

Here is an example JSON code, as it comes out from MySQL:

```
{\"id\":2335,\"editor\":{\"selected_shape\":\"spot-7488\"},\"general\":{\"name\":\"HTML Test\",\"shortcode\":\"html-test\",\"width\":1280,\"height\":776},\"spots\":[{\"id\":\"spot-7488\",\"x\":9.9,\"y\":22.6,\"default_style\":{\"use_icon\":1},\"tooltip_content\":{\"content_type\":\"content-builder\",\"plain_text\":\"<p class=\\\"test\\\">Test</p>\",\"squares_json\":\"{\\\"containers\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"sq-container-293021\\\",\\\"settings\\\":{\\\"elements\\\":[{\\\"settings\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Paragraph\\\",\\\"iconClass\\\":\\\"fa fa-paragraph\\\"},\\\"options\\\":{\\\"text\\\":{\\\"text\\\":\\\"<p class=\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\">Test</p>\\\"}}}]}}]}\"}}]}
```

And here is how it's supposed to look in order to get parsed correctly (using jsonlint.com to test):

```
{"id":2335,"editor":{"selected_shape":"spot-7488"},"general":{"name":"HTML Test","shortcode":"html-test","width":1280,"height":776},"spots":[{"id":"spot-7488","x":9.9,"y":22.6,"default_style":{"use_icon":1},"tooltip_content":{"content_type":"content-builder","plain_text":"<p class=\"test\">Test</p>","squares_json":"{\"containers\":[{\"id\":\"sq-container-293021\",\"settings\":{\"elements\":[{\"settings\":{\"name\":\"Paragraph\",\"iconClass\":\"fa fa-paragraph\"},\"options\":{\"text\":{\"text\":\"<p class=\\\"test\\\">Test</p>\"}}}]}}]}"}}]}
```

Please note that I have HTML code inside JSON, which is inside another JSON and this is where it gets a bit messy.

My question - is there a function or library for PHP (for JS will work too) which covers all those corner cases, because I'm sure someone will find a way to break the script.

Thanks!

Comment: Try stripslashes? ( http://php.net/stripslashes )  Although, if you have elaborate HTML in there, no guarantee that something won't break. You really need to fix this at the source if you can.

Comment: What do you mean "fix this at the source"?

Comment: The process you use to insert this JSON data into your database is adding these backslashes somewhere. You need to examine the process that captures the JSON and modify it to make sure the JSON goes unmolested.

Comment: It's the same thing whether I fix it before or after the database. Slashes are still being added when the JSON gets from the front-end to PHP via ajax.

Comment: In that case, you should fix the JSON coming via AJAX -- if possible. As you've already noted, the backslashes make for invalid JSON. What I mean to say is that somebody somewhere is adding slashes to JSON which causes it to be invalid. To know the reason would help solve the problem.

Comment: Then the problem is exactly the same as in my question - I need a way to remove slashes for nested JSON and HTML code.

Comment: Let me phrase this differently. Who is adding slashes to JSON, thereby making it invalid? At what stage are these slashes being added?

Comment: The slashes are being added when the javascript object gets sent to PHP via AJAX and it gets converted to JSON automatically (by PHP I think).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133160/discussion-between-s-imp-and-nikolay-dyankov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, which is woefully inadequate, is for you to use [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes). The reason this answer is not adequate is that your JSON string might have been *escaped* or had *addslashes* called on it multiple times and you would have to call stripslashes precisely once for each time this had happened.

The proper solution is to find out where the slashes are being added and either a) avoid adding the slashes or b) understand why the slashes are there and respond accordingly. I strongly believe that the process that creates that broken JSON is where the problem lies.

Slashes are typically added in PHP in a few cases:

- [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are turned on. This is an old PHP feature which has been removed. The basic idea is that PHP used to auto-escape quotes in incoming requests to let you just cram incoming strings into a db. Guess what? **NOT SAFE.**
- [add_slashes](http://php.net/addslashes) has been called. Why call this? Some folks use it as an incorrect means of escaping data before sticking stuff in a db. Others use it to keep HTML from breaking when echoing variables out (htmlspecialchars should probably be used instead). It can also come in handy in a variety of other *meta* situations when you are defining code in a string.
- When escaping data input. The most common escaping function is [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string). It's very important to escape values before inserting them in a db to prevent sql injection and other exploits but **you should never escape things twice.**

So there's a possibility that your code is double-escaping things or that addslashes is getting called or something like magic_quotes is causing the problem, but I suspect it is another problem: **some JS code might be supplying this JSON not as a proper JSON string, but one that has been escaped so to define a string *within javascript*.**

If you take your example JSON string above, and slap some quotes around it:

```
var myJSON = "<put your string here>";
```

then *SURPRISE* your javascript is not broken and the var myJSON contains a string that is actually valid JSON and can be parsed into an a valid JSON object:

```
var myJSON = "{\"id\":2335,\"editor\":{\"selected_shape\":\"spot-7488\"},\"general\":{\"name\":\"HTML Test\",\"shortcode\":\"html-test\",\"width\":1280,\"height\":776},\"spots\":[{\"id\":\"spot-7488\",\"x\":9.9,\"y\":22.6,\"default_style\":{\"use_icon\":1},\"tooltip_content\":{\"content_type\":\"content-builder\",\"plain_text\":\"<p class=\\\"test\\\">Test</p>\",\"squares_json\":\"{\\\"containers\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"sq-container-293021\\\",\\\"settings\\\":{\\\"elements\\\":[{\\\"settings\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Paragraph\\\",\\\"iconClass\\\":\\\"fa fa-paragraph\\\"},\\\"options\\\":{\\\"text\\\":{\\\"text\\\":\\\"<p class=\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\">Test</p>\\\"}}}]}}]}\"}}]}";
console.log(JSON.parse(myJSON)); // this is an actual object
```

The key here is to examine the point of entry where this JSON arrives in your system. I suspect some AJAX request has created some object and rather than sending valid JSON Of that object, it is sending instead an escaped string of a JSON object.

EDIT:

Here's a simple example of what happens when you have too many encodings. Try running this JS in your browser and observe the console output:

```
var myObj = {"key":"here is my value"};
console.log(myObj);
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
console.log(myJSON);
var doubleEncoded = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
console.log(doubleEncoded);
```

Comment: Very simple solution, I should have tried parsing the JSON in javascript directly, without trying to manually remove the slashes :)

Comment: I would suggest that you examine the input stage for this JSON and find out if you can avoid encoding them in the first place. There's probably one too many calls to JSON.stringify or something. When your JSON arrives in PHP, it should ideally not have all the extra slashes.